# How to get consistent results for Forecasting Asset Prices using Neural Networks

Tags: machine-learning, keras, neural-network, forecasting

I am trying to build a neural network to forecast the price of an financial asset using 4 input facotors (the price of oil, the USD value, Inflation and an index that is measuring the uncertainty in the economy)

To evaluate the model I want to compare the Mean Absolute Error of my prediction compared to the actual values of the test data.

But whenever I rerun my code I get a different result for the mean absolute error (without changing the model, just reruning the exact same code).

And I have no idea why that is the case.

This is my code:

First I load the data

```
data = pd.read_excel("data/Data_final.xlsx", index_col= "Date", parse_dates = True).dropna()
data = data["2020":"1985"].sort_values("Date", ascending = True)
```

Then I split the data into the input variables and the output variable (price of gold) and split the data into a training and a test set - I used shuffle = False to get the same train and test data set each time

```
x = data[["WTI_Crude_Oil", "US_CPI_all_Urban", "USDX", "Uncertainty_Index"]]
y = data.iloc[:,0]
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size =0.20, shuffle = False)
```

After that I normalize the data

```
mean_x = x_train.mean(axis = 0)
x_train = x_train - mean_x
std_x = x_train.std(axis = 0)
x_train = x_train / std_x
# normalize test data as well using mean and std of train data to avoid look ahead bias 
x_test = x_test - mean_x
x_test = x_test / std_x
```

Then I am build my model

```
from keras import models
from keras import layers
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation = "relu", input_shape = (x_train.shape[1],)))
model.add(layers.Dense(16, activation = "relu"))
model.add(layers.Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer = "rmsprop", loss = "mse", metrics = ["mae"])
```

Then I fit and evaluate the model

```
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs = 600)
test_mse_score, test_mae_score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
```

My goal is to reduce the Mean absolute error, but for every time I run the code I get a different Mean Absolute Error. Where is the mistake in my code? [Snippet of the data for better understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNDFe.png)

Comment: How different? There is an inherent randomness here, starting from the `train_test_split` and including the model itself, so the results will never be identical between different runs. Have you taken this into account?

Comment: Did I not prevent the randomness from train_test_split by the argument shuffle = false? If I check the split of the data in each run the test data sets and the train data sets are the same in each run. 

What do you mean by including the model itself? 

Sometimes the mean absolute error of the model is around 50, in the next run like 57, then 52, then 62 it varies by quit a bit. My goal is to solve this issue, that the MAE is not so much different each time. Some variation should be normal I guess? Since I dont set initial weights for the model and the model learns different each time?

Comment: You are right re `shuffle=False` - I missed that. But the model starts with different random initial weights each time. An MAE between 50-62 may signify a big difference or may not, depending on the scale of your predicted data and the size of your dataset: smaller datasets tend to give greater variation, and if the scale of your output is in the thousands then the difference is negligible.

Comment: I am trying to forecast the gold price. For the test data the gold price varies between 1200 and 2000. So I think an MAE of 50-62 is still somewhat to large. But I actually dont know what to improve further.
If I set initial weights the results should be closer together at end right? But is there a best practice on which initial weights to start with or is it just trial and error?

Comment: And yes my data set is pretty small containing only 430 monthly observations in total of which I use 387 for training and 43 for testing

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from pandas_datareader import data as wb
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pylab import rcParams
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler


start = '2019-06-30'
end = '2020-06-30'

tickers = ['SBUX']

thelen = len(tickers)

price_data = []
for ticker in tickers:
    prices = wb.DataReader(ticker, start = start, end = end, data_source='yahoo')[['Open','Adj Close']]
    price_data.append(prices.assign(ticker=ticker)[['ticker', 'Open', 'Adj Close']])

#names = np.reshape(price_data, (len(price_data), 1))

df = pd.concat(price_data)
df.reset_index(inplace=True)

for col in df.columns: 
    print(col) 
    
#used for setting the output figure size
rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 20,10
#to normalize the given input data
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
#to read input data set (place the file name inside  ' ') as shown below
df.head()

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date,format='%Y-%m-%d')
# df.index = names['Date']
#3plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))
# plt.plot(df['Adj Close'], label='Closing Price')


ntrain = 80
df_train = df.head(int(len(df)*(ntrain/100)))
ntest = -80
df_test = df.tail(int(len(df)*(ntest/100)))


#importing the packages 
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, LSTM

#dataframe creation
seriesdata = df.sort_index(ascending=True, axis=0)
new_seriesdata = pd.DataFrame(index=range(0,len(df)),columns=['Date','Adj Close'])
length_of_data=len(seriesdata)
for i in range(0,length_of_data):
    new_seriesdata['Date'][i] = seriesdata['Date'][i]
    new_seriesdata['Adj Close'][i] = seriesdata['Adj Close'][i]
#setting the index again
new_seriesdata.index = new_seriesdata.Date
new_seriesdata.drop('Date', axis=1, inplace=True)
#creating train and test sets this comprises the entire data’s present in the dataset
myseriesdataset = new_seriesdata.values
totrain = myseriesdataset[0:255,:]
tovalid = myseriesdataset[255:,:]
#converting dataset into x_train and y_train
scalerdata = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
scale_data = scalerdata.fit_transform(myseriesdataset)
x_totrain, y_totrain = [], []
length_of_totrain=len(totrain)
for i in range(60,length_of_totrain):
    x_totrain.append(scale_data[i-60:i,0])
    y_totrain.append(scale_data[i,0])
x_totrain, y_totrain = np.array(x_totrain), np.array(y_totrain)
x_totrain = np.reshape(x_totrain, (x_totrain.shape[0],x_totrain.shape[1],1))


#LSTM neural network
lstm_model = Sequential()
lstm_model.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(x_totrain.shape[1],1)))
lstm_model.add(LSTM(units=50))
lstm_model.add(Dense(1))
lstm_model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adadelta')
lstm_model.fit(x_totrain, y_totrain, epochs=10, batch_size=1, verbose=2)
#predicting next data stock price
myinputs = new_seriesdata[len(new_seriesdata) - (len(tovalid)+1) - 60:].values
myinputs = myinputs.reshape(-1,1)
myinputs  = scalerdata.transform(myinputs)
tostore_test_result = []
for i in range(60,myinputs.shape[0]):
    tostore_test_result.append(myinputs[i-60:i,0])
tostore_test_result = np.array(tostore_test_result)
tostore_test_result = np.reshape(tostore_test_result,(tostore_test_result.shape[0],tostore_test_result.shape[1],1))
myclosing_priceresult = lstm_model.predict(tostore_test_result)
myclosing_priceresult = scalerdata.inverse_transform(myclosing_priceresult)

    
totrain = df_train
tovalid = df_test

#predicting next data stock price
myinputs = new_seriesdata[len(new_seriesdata) - (len(tovalid)+1) - 60:].values

#  Printing the next day’s predicted stock price. 
print(len(tostore_test_result));
print(myclosing_priceresult);
```

Result:

```
Date
ticker
Open
Adj Close
Epoch 1/10
193/193 - 3s - loss: 0.2868
Epoch 2/10
193/193 - 3s - loss: 0.2671
Epoch 3/10
193/193 - 3s - loss: 0.2465
Epoch 4/10
193/193 - 3s - loss: 0.2253
Epoch 5/10
193/193 - 3s - loss: 0.2040
Epoch 6/10
193/193 - 3s - loss: 0.1827
Epoch 7/10
193/193 - 3s - loss: 0.1617
Epoch 8/10
193/193 - 3s - loss: 0.1413
Epoch 9/10
193/193 - 3s - loss: 0.1217
Epoch 10/10
193/193 - 3s - loss: 0.1033
1
[[67.15351]]
```

Comment: I tried to run your code, but I run into an error in the second line of the LSTM Model: 
NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor (lstm_1/strided_slice:0) to a numpy array. This error may indicate that you're trying to pass a Tensor to a NumPy call, which is not supported.

What your code basically does it takes the prices of the last 60 trading days and predicts the price of the following day? 
I have monthly data from 1985 to 2020 and what to train a model on ~80% of the data and use the model to make prediction for the test period and compare it (using MAE and a plot)

Comment: Because of the error I cannot run your full code to completly understand what it actually does and then apply it to my model

Comment: I tested the code yesterday and got an error. It was very weird! It seemed like the Yahoo web reader, or more likely the API, went down for a few hours. Anyway, now, I just ran the code that I shared with you, and it seems to be working fine. Please try it again and share your feedback.

Comment: Thank you for replying again!
So in jupiter Notebook I got the same error again but in PyCharm it works perfectly fine. 
Now I want to customize the code to my specific problem. In your code only the past prices are used to predict the future price. My goal is to predict the next months gold price based on 4 different input factors (you can see a snippet of my data in the initial question). But I have difficulties to transform my data into the right shape that the LSTM model is able to process the data.